# dlclose not releasing the library handle in case static class members are accessed like calling boost::this_fiber::get_id()

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, boost-fiber

I have a scenario as bellow and not able to close the library

liba.so

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>
  using namespace std;

  int func1(int)
  {
    cout << "this fiber id " << boost::this_fiber::get_id() << endl; // if this line is commented out then the problem resolved.
    cout << "It is a func1" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
```

---

### I created a library out of the cpp file where -fno-unique-symbol is specified so that it should not hold back the symbol.

main code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;
int fun(string & flName)  {
  void *handle;
  typedef int (*fn)(int);
  fn fn1;
  handle = dlopen(flName.c_str(), RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_LAZY);
  fn1 = (fn)dlsym(handle, "_Z5func1I");
  (*fn1)(2);
  cout << "handle :" << handle << endl;
  int ext_code = dlclose(handle);
  printf ("end exit code %d\n", ext_code);
}

int main(void)    {
  std::string fileName("dirpath/liba.so");
   fun(fileName);
   fun(fileName);
   fun(fileName);
   return 0;
}
```

output, when this_fiber is commented out

- handle : 0x234567
- end exit code 0
- handle :0x345678
- end exit code 0
- handle : 0x456789
- end exit code 0

----- but when this_fiber::get_id() is active then

- handle : 0x234567
- end exit code 0
- handle :0x234567
- end exit code 0
- handle : 0x234567
- end exit code 0

Can someone explain the reason for holding back the library handle and tell me how to tweak the code so that I can close the library

Comment: `dlclose` returned 0, so you did successfully close the library.

Comment: Mind you, `printf("handle=%p\n", handle);` would be more reliable.

Comment: Although I got 0 as a return value of the dlclose but if I add one static variable and assigned it to some value then, in the dlopen call the value of that static variable was remain the same as the updated value and not re-initialized.

Comment: Guess you actually meant to ask: _why dlclose doesn't unload the shared library?_ Most likely because the refence-counter didn't become zero. Guess this boot/fiber might be responsible for it.

Comment: Looks like the use of thread_local in boost code may causing the problem